# Como hago para corregir el error al desplegar app Flask en Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

*Buenas compañeros, hice deploy de una app python-flask en heroku no me arroja ningún error me da el mensaje de success!! pero al intentar abrir el enlace sale el siguiente mensaje.*

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

- Tengo mi archivo Procfile configurado

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

- Tengo mi archivo requirements.txt con las libs
- se instalo gunicorn y python-decouple

Este es el log de Heroku

```
2021-10-30T00:58:29.494473+00:00 app[web.1]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: inicio_sesion.html

2021-10-30T00:58:29.495141+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.16.69 - - [30/Oct/2021:00:58:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36"

2021-10-30T01:30:32.853680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling

2021-10-30T01:30:32.857956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down

2021-10-30T01:30:35.468344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

2021-10-30T01:30:35.690877+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-30 01:30:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term

2021-10-30T01:30:35.691186+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-30 01:30:35 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)

2021-10-30T01:30:35.691700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-30 01:30:35 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2021-10-30T01:30:35.791368+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-10-30 01:30:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2021-10-30T01:30:35.948240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Esos son los requisitos me pueden ayudar!!!!

Comment: revisa la consola de logs de heroku, ahí está el error

Comment: El sitio está en español y la publicación debe estar unicamente en español

Comment: gracias,,,, lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: El error te dice que la plantilla `inicio_sesion.html` no se ha encontrado

Comment: Ese es el caso esa plantilla y la app corre local pero al subirla a heroku no.

Comment: listo ya fue solucionado y coloco la solución para que sea tenida en cuenta al momento de hacer la estructura del proyecto se nombraron las carpetas con la letra inicial en mayúscula porque eso no tomaba la carpeta templates ni static . fue solucionado cambiando esta por su inicial en minuscula.

Comment: Si ya encontraste una respuesta, ¡ponla como respuesta, no como comentario! Así podrás [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) una vez que transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

El diagnostico fue que el motivo por el cual no se encontraban las templates es porque la estructura del programa(las carpetas), iniciaban su nombre con mayúscula y flask no las reconocía, por tal forma esto fue cambiado. así mismo se integro el uso de jinja2 para modular el código.